# App crashing after pressing a button with: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android

The button worked fine (without crashing) but after I made that it would write information into an `ArrayList` for the `ListView` (which is not yet used) it started crashing. What is causing this and how to fix it?

The code I added (different activity, but I use the activity with the button via `startActivityForResult`. It get's the information declared in `onActivityResult` and the other function puts all of the information into the `ArrayList`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String addName = data.getStringExtra("Name");
                String addPrice = data.getStringExtra("Price");
                String addAmmount = data.getStringExtra("Ammount");
                boolean pressed = data.getBooleanExtra("Pressed", FALSE);

                int ammount = Integer.parseInt(addAmmount);
                int currentprice = Integer.parseInt(addPrice);
                int intval = ammount * currentprice;

                portfoliolist.add(new PortfolioItem(addName, ammount, intval, 0, 0, 0));

                GetPrice();
            }
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

            }
        }
    }

    private void GetPrice(){

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    final String myResponce = response.body().string();

                    globalCoin.clear();

                    try {
                        JSONArray coins = new JSONArray(myResponce);
                        for(int i = 0; i < coins.length(); i++){
                            try {
                                JSONObject coin = coins.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = coin.getString("name");
                                String price = coin.getString("price_usd");
                                String change = coin.getString("percent_change_24h");

                                globalCoin.add(new Coin(name, price, change));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < globalCoin.size(); i++){
            for(int ii = 0; ii < portfoliolist.size(); ii++){
                if(globalCoin.get(i).getName() == portfoliolist.get(ii).name){
                    int gottenprice = Integer.parseInt(globalCoin.get(i).getPrice());
                    portfoliolist.get(ii).price = gottenprice;
                    portfoliolist.get(ii).curvalue = portfoliolist.get(ii).price * portfoliolist.get(ii).ammount;
                    portfoliolist.get(ii).change = portfoliolist.get(ii).curvalue / portfoliolist.get(ii).intvalue - 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

EDIT: logcat log:

```html
05-05 18:26:33.121 28991-28991/com.example.vartotojas.heycrypto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vartotojas.heycrypto, PID: 28991
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.vartotojas.heycrypto/com.example.vartotojas.heycrypto.PortfolioActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.vartotojas.heycrypto.PortfolioActivity.onActivityResult(PortfolioActivity.java:113)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: what is logcat saying?

Comment: @SabaJafarzadeh added logcat log

Comment: `portfoliolist` is null. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384

Comment: @MikeM. I'm sorry that I did not include this, but I have `ArrayList<PortfolioItem> portfoliolist;` way above and after reading the article you sent, it doesn't seem this would cause it or am I mistaken?

Comment: That's only the declaration. You've not actually instantiated and assigned an `ArrayList` to `portfoliolist`.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by NullPointerException. Initialize your portfolioList before adding items to it like this:

```
portfolioList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I initialized it in the `onCreate`, yet the app is still crashing with the same logcat

Comment: Never mind, thanks everyone for the help! The `globalcoin` list wasn't initialized aswell

Answer (score 0):

As you see on `java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference` you are getting null pointer exception.
Probably portfoliolist is null. Or check which other list is null

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnActivityResult` method the line:

```
portfoliolist.add(new PortfolioItem(addName, ammount, intval, 0, 0, 0));
```

is showing the error. Since the List `portfoliolist`is `null`.
You should always check for the `NullPointerException` by using the `if-else` checks or `try catch`

```
if(portfoliolist != null){
    // add the item to list
}else{
    // first instantiate and then add item to list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object in java without initiating it. In your code you did not initiated `ArrayList` and you are adding items in it.

Just replace your part of code with this in `onActivityResult()` method.

```
   int intval = ammount * currentprice;
   if(portfoliolist == null) portfoliolist = new ArrayList(); // i added this line
   portfoliolist.add(new PortfolioItem(addName, ammount, intval, 0, 0, 0));
```